# Wamp not loading extension

Tags: php, wamp, xcache

I've installed an xcache extension for php, I've added the file in the ext folder `php_xcache.dll` then added this to php.ini:

```
extension=php_xcache.dll
```

then the extension was appeared in the extension list of wamp, I'am trying to activate it, the server restarts, then I look again at the list and the xcache is still NOT activated, also I've viewed the:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r(get_loaded_extensions());
echo '</pre>';
exit;
```

and there are not xcache extension loaded, also there are no errors while loading the extension after I've click "Exit" in the WAMP tree icon, and then restart it clicking the icon on desctop, any ideas on how to fix this?

the self extension file should be fine because I've downloaded it from the official site compatible with my php version

Comment: You may see the error for the extension not loading in your php error log - I don't think WAMP would alert you. Are both WAMP and the extension 32-bit?

Comment: You need the `Thread Safe` version fo run with WAMP

Answer (score 0):

I think the line should be just: extension=xcache

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it